# Javascript RegExp being interpreted different from a string vs from a data-attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

Long story short, I'm trying to "fix" my system so I'm using the same regular expressions on the backend as we are the front (validating both sides for obvious security reasons). I've got my regex server side working just fine, but getting it down to the client is a pain. My quickest thought was to simply store it in a data attribute on a tag, grab it, and then validate against it.

Well, me, think again! JS is throwing me for a loop because apparently RegExp interprets the string differently depending how it's pulled in. Can anyone shine some light on what is happening here or how I might go about resolving this issue

HTML

```
<span data-regex="(^\\d{5}$)|(^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$)"></span>
```

Javascript

```
new RegExp($0.dataset.regex)
//returns /(^\\d{5}$)|(^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$)/

new RegExp($($0).data('regex'))
//returns /(^\\d{5}$)|(^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$)/

new RegExp("(^\\d{5}$)|(^\\d{5}-\\d{4}$)");
//returns /(^\d{5}$)|(^\d{5}-\d{4}$)/
```

Note in the first two how if I pull the value from the data attribute dynamically, the constructor for `RegExp` for some reason doesn't interpret the double slash correctly. If, however, I copy and paste the value as a string and call `RegExp` on the value, it correctly interprets the double slash and returns it in the right pattern.

I've also attempted simply not escaping the `\d` character by double slashing on the server side, but as you might (or might not) have guessed, the opposite happens. When pulled from attributes/dataset, the \ is completely removed leading the Regex to think I'm looking for the "d" character rather than digits. I'm at a loss for understanding what JS is thinking here. Please send help, Internet

Answer (score 2):

Your data attribute has redundant backslashes. There's no need to escape backslashes in HTML attributes, so you'll actually get a double-backslash where you don't want one. When writing regular expressions as strings in JavaScript you have to escape backslashes, of course.

So you don't actually have the same string on both sides, simply because escaping works differently.

Comment: Apparently I'm just actually going insane or must have mistyped something on my first tests because I just tried again with the non-escaped html attribute (i.e. just single slashed for `\d`) and it worked correctly. 

I'm still not sure I wholly understand the reasoning behind why the attribute isn't equivalent to the string by itself though. If I add another like `<span data-bork="bork">` and run `element.dataset.bork == "bork"` it returns `true`. Why is this different for `data-regex="\bork" == "\bork"`?

Comment: Because `\b` in that *string* is actually the backspace character, while `\b` in that *attribute* is the two characters \ and b. You can do that in reverse as well, e.g. `&apos;` in the attribute is `'`, while it's the exact letters `&apos;` when placed in a JS string.